# How can I implement a Token Generator?

Tags: php, laravel

I am making an API with Laravel and I want to consume the ApiMedic API.

The following is my `DiagnosisClient`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class DiagnosisClient { 

    private $healthServiceUrl; 
    private $language;
    private $token;
    private $validThrough;

    # constructor
    function __construct($language) {
        $this->token = Config::get('services.apimedic_key');
        $this->validThrough = $this->getTokenValidThrough();
        $this->healthServiceUrl = Config::get('services.health_service_url');
        $this->language = $language;
    }

 
    private function _loadFromWebserice($action)
    {
        $extraArgs = 'token='.$this->token.'&format=json&language='.$this->language;
        $extraChar = strpos($action, '?') ? '&' : '?';
        $url = $this->healthServiceUrl.'/'.$action.$extraChar.$extraArgs;

        var_dump($url);
        $response = Http::get($url);
        $result = $response->body();
        $obj = json_decode($result, true);

        if ($response->status() != 200) {
            // Handle error from the server
            // You can throw an exception or return an appropriate response
            return null;
        }

        return $obj;
    }       
    
    private function getTokenValidThrough()
    {
        $tokenParts = explode('.', $this->token);
        if (count($tokenParts) !== 3) {
            return null;
        }

        $payload = base64_decode($tokenParts[1]);
        $data = json_decode($payload, true);
        return $data['ValidThrough'] ?? null;
    }

    public function loadSymptoms() { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('symptoms'); 
    } 
    
    
    public function loadIssues() { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('issues'); 
    } 
    
    public function loadIssueInfo($issueId) { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('issues/'.$issueId.'/info'); 
    } 
    
  
    # <param name="$yearOfBirth">Selected person year of born</param>
    # <returns>Returns calculated array of potential issues for selected parameters</returns>
    public function loadDiagnosis($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth) { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('diagnosis?symptoms='.json_encode($selectedSymptoms).'&gender='.$gender.'&year_of_birth='.$yearOfBirth); 
    } 
    
    
    public function loadSpecialisations($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth) { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('diagnosis/specialisations?symptoms='.json_encode($selectedSymptoms).'&gender='.$gender.'&year_of_birth='.$yearOfBirth); 
    } 
    
    
    public function loadBodyLocations() { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('body/locations'); 
    }
    
    
    public function loadBodySublocations($bodyLocationId) { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('body/locations/'.$bodyLocationId); 
    }
    
    
    public function loadSublocationSymptoms($sublocationId, $selectedSelectorStatus) { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('symptoms/'.$sublocationId.'/'.$selectedSelectorStatus); 
    }
    
    
    public function loadProposedSymptoms($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth) { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('symptoms/proposed?symptoms='.json_encode($selectedSymptoms).'&gender='.$gender.'&year_of_birth='.$yearOfBirth); 
    } 
    
    
    public function loadRedFlag($symptomId) { 
        return $this->_loadFromWebserice('redflag?symptomId='.$symptomId); 
    } 

}
```

And this is my `ApiMedicService`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Http\Services\TokenGenerator;

class ApiMedicService
{
    protected $diagnosisClient;

    public function __construct($language)
    {
        $this->diagnosisClient = new DiagnosisClient($language);
    }

    public function loadSymptoms()
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadSymptoms();
    }

    public function loadIssues()
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadIssues();
    }

    public function loadIssueInfo($issueId)
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadIssueInfo($issueId);
    }

    public function loadDiagnosis($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth)
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadDiagnosis($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth);
    }

    public function loadSpecialisations($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth)
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadSpecialisations($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth);
    }

    public function loadBodyLocations()
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadBodyLocations();
    }

    public function loadBodySublocations($bodyLocationId)
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadBodySublocations($bodyLocationId);
    }

    public function loadSublocationSymptoms($sublocationId, $selectedSelectorStatus)
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadSublocationSymptoms($sublocationId, $selectedSelectorStatus);
    }

    public function loadProposedSymptoms($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth)
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadProposedSymptoms($selectedSymptoms, $gender, $yearOfBirth);
    }

    public function loadRedFlag($symptomId)
    {
        return $this->diagnosisClient->loadRedFlag($symptomId);
    }
}
```

SymptomsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Services\DiagnosisClient;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class SymptomsController extends Controller
{
    protected $diagnosisClient;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $language = 'en-gb';
        $this->diagnosisClient = app()->make(DiagnosisClient::class, ['language' => $language]);
    }

    public function getAllSymptoms()
    {
        $symptoms = $this->diagnosisClient->loadSymptoms();

        return response()->json($symptoms);
    }

    public function getIssues()
    {
        $issues = $this->diagnosisClient->loadIssues();

        return response()->json($issues);
    }

    public function getDiagnoses(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'symptoms' => 'required|array',
            'symptoms.*' => 'numeric',
        ]);

        $symptoms = $request->input('symptoms');
        $user = Auth::user();
        $gender = $user->gender;
        $birth_date = Carbon::parse($user->birth_date)->format('Y');

        $diagnoses = $this->diagnosisClient->loadDiagnosis($symptoms, $gender, $birth_date);

        return response()->json($diagnoses);
    }

    
}
```

All of the code above works fine. I can make a request to my endpoint `/diagnosis` fine.
The issue is that the token that is being passed to the url is constantly changing.
And through the apimedic docs they provide a TokenGenerator.php file which is the following.

```
<?php
    class TokenGenerator
    {
        private $authServiceUrl = ''; 
        private $username = '';
        private $password = '';
        
        # constructor
        function __construct($username, $pasword, $authServiceUrl) {
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->password = $pasword;
            $this->authServiceUrl = $authServiceUrl;
        }
        
        # <summary>
        # loadToken function. Gets a token from $authServiceUrl.
        # </summary>
        # <param name="$username">api user username</param>
        # <param name="$password">api user password</param>
        # <param name="$authServiceUrl">priaid login url (https://authservice.priaid.ch/login)</param>
        # <returns>Returns deserialized token object. It has 2 properties: 'Token' and 'ValidThrough'</returns>
        public function loadToken()
        {
            $computedHash = base64_encode(hash_hmac ( 'md5' , $this->authServiceUrl , $this->password, true ));
            $authorization = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$this->username.':'.$computedHash;
            
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->authServiceUrl);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            $obj = json_decode($result);
            $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            
            if ($info['http_code'] != '200') {
                throw new Exception('Failed to load token');
            }
            
            return $obj;
        }
    }
?>
```

But i am not being able to implement this TokenGenerator to my api.

I have the following keys in my .env file:

```
HEALTH_SERVICE_URL=https://sandbox-healthservice.priaid.ch
AUTH_SERVICE_URL=https://authservice.priaid.ch/login
APIMEDIC_USERNAME=<USERNAME>
APIMEDIC_PASSWORD=<PASSWORD>
```

So in my diagnosis client I want to use the generated token and the validThrough.

This I should get them by the object that is being returned by `loadToken` in TokenGenerator.php.

Comment: `i am not being able to implement this TokenGenerator` ...because? What exactly is the issue? What did you try? What was the specific problem? See also [ask]

Comment: Just store the token and expiry date into a database and query it before each request? Problems solved?

Comment: @maio290 wouldn´t affect the fact that the token changes through time? Because it is valid through a lapse of time.

Comment: @tukitooo1998 You obviously need to implement an update mechanism, yes. But that's basically how it is done in several applications I've developed and I never had an issue with it. It's just _one_ approach, not _the_ approach. We know next to nothing about your application or your problems with the token generator. That's why you should clarify your problem and heed ADyson's comment ;)

Comment: 1. All of the code above the TokenGenerator snippet is irrelevant. 2. If the library doesn't implement the functionality that you want, the you're going to have to do it yourself. We can help you do that, but you're going to have to make an effort first.